# Установка MS Sql Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

После установки вышеуказанного продукта и Management Studio при попытке открыть уже имеющуюся БД возникает ошибка:
"There is no editor available for 'filename.mdf'. Make sure the application for the file type (.mdf) is installed."
 Судя по всему, требуется переустановка. Как правильно установить приложения для работы с данными файлами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mdf файлы не открываются в Management Studio, это клиент для подключения к SQL Server'у, из него можно открыть, например, sql-файлы. MDF - это файл базы данных, чтобы базу присоединить к SQL Server'у, надо в студии подключиться к серверу, правой кнопкой по разделу с базами щелкнуть, и выбрать "Подключить базу" или "Attach base", что то вроде этого.